# Указать следующие количество нужного "опыта" PHP

Tags: php

Целый день ломаю голову над одным нужным кодом.
Суть такова — есть такой список:

```
Уровень | Количество требуемого опыта
1       |   28
2       |   52
3       |   92
4       |   148
..      |   ..
```

(и так до бесконечности)

Задача: Человек вводит уровень например `14`, и ему выводит количество необходимого опыта.

Comment: Где код? Вопрос непонятный.

Comment: Если это делается для какой-то "игры" (не суть даже), то в чем проблема: а) заполнить таблицу нужными значениями или б) написать формулу, которая принимает номер уровня, а отдает кол-во опыта?

Comment: и формулу подскажет (`y=4*(2*(x^2)+5)`) и следующие числа в ряду http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=28,+52,+92,+148

Answer (score 0):

Предположительно, что это - последовательность чисел, а не просто список.
Предположительно, что описывается она как `Xi = 2X(i-1) - 4 * 3^(i-2)`

Сим следует, что самое простое решение для существующей задачи есть сий код:

```
function sequence(int $level) : int {
    if($level < 1) throw new Exception('Level must be at least 1');
    if($level == 1) return 28;
    return sequence(--$level) * 2 - 4 * pow(3, --$level);
}
```

> Однако хотелось бы заметить, что такая последовательность, вероятно,
>   ошибочна, в связи с тем, что после 5 элемента кол-во опыта идёт на
>   уменьшения и начиная с 7 элемента кол-во опыта уходит в минус.

Comment: Проблема в том что следующее число после 148 неизвестно